# How many controllers should a MS Web API microservice have?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm trying to set up a small learning project with a microservice architecture. I'm just  wondering: how many controllers should a microservice have?

At the moment I have two tables: books (title, language, category etc.) and author (first name, last name, birth date etc.). Each of them has an entity, a DTO, a repository and a controller.

- /api/books/
- /api/authors/

For me it would totally make sense to have two controllers: BooksControllers and AuthorsControllers. Both are in the first microservice (in this case also WebApi project)

Later on I will add a second microservice "sales figures". It would container sales figures for the books (and maybe later on sales figures for other stuff).

Is this a good approach?

Comment: Every microservice should deal with objects that fall under the same bounded context. You can have as many controllers you want provided they cater the same bounded context. In your example both book and author contributes to the same bounded context and it looks legitimate.

Answer (score 2):

Microservices need to be

- Independently deployable
- Loosely coupled
- Highly maintainable and testable

So it is not about the controllers count. It's about how independent and loosely coupled they are. For example if the "sales figures" service is down it should not effect the "books and authors" and wise versa.

In my opinion, I think your approach is good.